# Using a primefaces dialog on multiple buttons in an XHTML form / Java PrimeFaces

Tags: java, dialog, primefaces

I have a problem and I am pretty new for primefaces and JSF altogether, probably it is my lack of knowledge, but I couldn't find an answer yet, I have XHTML-s, on the main one I have several buttons, and I wrote one feedback dialog which tells that the operation successful, and the name of operation.

The dialog appears, looks fine, but the message is always what I specified on the last button.
Perhaps I misunderstood something with the concept, can anybody help me what am I doing wrong?

here are the code:

Bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ActionSuccessController extends AbstractAction implements
    Serializable {

public String setParam(String actionName) {
    ResourceBundle messageBundle = ResourceBundle
            .getBundle("hu.avhga.web.partner.messages");
    description = messageBundle.getString("actionSuccess");
    this.actionName = actionName;
    return "";
}
...
```

Main XHTML where I have the buttons

```
...
                            <p:commandButton id="lock"
                            value="#{msg['PartnerAdmin.button.lock']}" 
                            action="#{partnerAccountAdminAction.lock}" 
                            update=":partnerAccountAdminForm :actionSuccessForm"
                            disabled="#{partnerAccountAdminAction.disabledButtonMap.get('LOCK')}"
                            rendered="#{partnerAccountAdminAction.passwordAdmin}"
                            styleClass="gold"
                            onclick="#{actionSuccessController.setParam(msg['PartnerAdmin.button.lock'])}"
                            oncomplete="usersTableWidget.filter();actionSuccessDialogVar.show();"/>

                        <p:commandButton id="unlock"
                            value="#{msg['PartnerAdmin.button.unlock']}" 
                            action="#{partnerAccountAdminAction.unlock}"
                            update=":partnerAccountAdminForm :actionSuccessForm"
                            disabled="#{partnerAccountAdminAction.disabledButtonMap.get('UNLOCK')}"
                            rendered="#{partnerAccountAdminAction.passwordAdmin}"
                            styleClass="gold"
                            onclick="#{actionSuccessController.setParam(msg['PartnerAdmin.button.unlock'])}"
                            oncomplete="usersTableWidget.filter();actionSuccessDialogVar.show();"/>

                        <p:commandButton id="suspend"
                            value="#{msg['PartnerAdmin.button.suspend']}" 
                            action="#{partnerAccountAdminAction.suspend}"
                            update=":partnerAccountAdminForm :actionSuccessForm"
                            disabled="#{partnerAccountAdminAction.disabledButtonMap.get('SUSPEND')}"
                            rendered="#{partnerAccountAdminAction.userAdmin}"
                            styleClass="gold"
                            onclick="#{actionSuccessController.setParam(msg['PartnerAdmin.button.suspend'])}"
                            oncomplete="usersTableWidget.filter();actionSuccessDialogVar.show();"/>

                        <p:commandButton id="remove"
                            value="#{msg['PartnerAdmin.button.remove']}" 
                            action="#{partnerAccountAdminAction.remove}"
                            update=":partnerAccountAdminForm :actionSuccessForm"
                            disabled="#{partnerAccountAdminAction.disabledButtonMap.get('REMOVE')}"
                            rendered="#{partnerAccountAdminAction.userAdmin}"
                            styleClass="gold"
                            onclick="#{actionSuccessController.setParam(msg['PartnerAdmin.button.remove'])}"
                            oncomplete="usersTableWidget.filter();actionSuccessDialogVar.show();"/>
...
```

After this I have the import of the following XHTML:

```
<p:dialog id="actionSuccessDialogId" header="#{actionSuccessController.actionName}"
        styleClass="dialog" closable="false"
        widgetVar="actionSuccessDialogVar" modal="true" appendToBody="true" dynamic="true"
        resizable="false" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode">
    <h:form id="actionSuccessForm" style="text-align:center;">
        <h:outputText value="#{actionSuccessController.description}" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <p:commandButton id="okButtonId" value="#{msg['Common.ok']}"
                        onclick="actionSuccessDialogVar.hide()" 
                        type="button" />
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

I am sure that these "setParam"s run always and for me it seems without reason.
So again the question why I always get the name of "remove" property. Is it because of ajax? Or because these all run when I click somewhere? I am a bit confused. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell, onclick can't call a setter like that. What you seem to want is to pass a parameter to your bean action, right?  In that case, you want to use the f:setPropertyActionListener tag. So your button would look like this:

```
<p:commandButton id="unlock"
                    value="#{msg['PartnerAdmin.button.unlock']}" 
                    action="#{partnerAccountAdminAction.unlock}"
                    update=":partnerAccountAdminForm :actionSuccessForm"
                    disabled="#{partnerAccountAdminAction.disabledButtonMap.get('UNLOCK')}"
                    rendered="#{partnerAccountAdminAction.passwordAdmin}"
                    styleClass="gold"
                    oncomplete="usersTableWidget.filter();actionSuccessDialogVar.show();">
      <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{actionSuccessController.param}" value="#{msg['PartnerAdmin.button.lock']}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

The f:setPropertyActionListener invokes the setter specified in the target with the value specified in the value attribute.

Comment: It helped a bit, instead of param and used #{ ... }, I used the fields of course like actionName, debug shows it gets the param, but the dialog is blank

so the line is: 
<f:setPropertyActionListener target="actionSuccessController.actionName" value="#{msg['PartnerAdmin.button.lock']}" />

Comment: I am pretty sure you need the #{...} syntax for the target, like this: target="#{actionSuccessController.actionName}". Just make sure you have a getter/setter for the actionName property.

Comment: yes, yes, and it works perfectly, except it seems like it was set after actionSuccessDialogVar.show() executes. Maybe that's why I can't see anything on the dialog. Anyways thanks for this already, I am hoping I find the next step here or with hard work.

Comment: actionSuccessDialogVar.show() is set to execute on complete, which means the browser will run that piece of code after it gets the response for the ajax request. In other words, it doesn't happen after  actionSuccessDialogVar.show(); it happens right before. What is probably going on is that your dialog is not getting updated properly. Wrap the dialog with a panelGroup, give that panelGroup and id and add that id to the update attribute. PS: post your full xhtml page, it might be a little easier to help you.

Comment: Right, and thanks, the solution worked, I forgot something to do.
instead of update=":partnerAccountAdminForm :actionSuccessForm" I needed update=":partnerAccountAdminForm :actionSuccessDialogId" now works fine. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With great help of Andre the final solution was:

```
<p:commandButton id="lock" immediate="true"
                            value="#{msg['PartnerAdmin.button.lock']}" 
                            action="#{partnerAccountAdminAction.lock}" 
                            update=":partnerAccountAdminForm :actionSuccessDialogId"
                            disabled="#{partnerAccountAdminAction.disabledButtonMap.get('LOCK')}"
                            rendered="#{partnerAccountAdminAction.passwordAdmin}"
                            styleClass="gold"
                            oncomplete="usersTableWidget.filter();actionSuccessDialogVar.show();">
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{actionSuccessController.actionName}" value="#{msg['PartnerAdmin.button.lock']}" />
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{actionSuccessController.description}" value="#{msg['PartnerAdmin.button.lock']}"/>
                            </p:commandButton>
```

hope it helps somebody who is encountering similar problem.
I added two setproperty line and changed the update parameter to "... :actionSuccessDialogId" so it works on the whole dialog.